# How do I add avatar component on top of material-ui card component? (React)

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, user-experience

I am new to React. I am trying to create react card for profile page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CazD.jpg). Basically, I want avatar component on top of the material-ui card as shown in the image.

How do I do that?
Thanks.
Here is my code so far

```
// profile.css

.getMoreContainer {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```
// profile.js
<div className="getMoreContainer">
    <Card style={{position: 'relative'}}>
       <Avatar src={LikeButton}
               style={{ position: 'absolute', 
                        marginTop: '-5%', 
                        marginLeft: '6%', 
                        zIndex: 5}} 
        />
         Get More Boosts
    </Card>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <Card>
       <Typography>Get More Potatoes</Typography>
     </Card>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any errors?

Comment: I can't overlay the avatar component and the card component. I'll update the question to add my code.